# Debugging crash in small object optimization for type erasure

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, type-erasure

I'm implementing a class that performs type erasure for small objects and have encountered a segmentation fault which I do not understand.

The following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct small_object
{
  public:
    template<class T>
    small_object(const T& value)
    {
      new(&storage_) concrete<T>(value);
    }

    ~small_object()
    {
      get_abstract().~abstract();
    }

    void print() const
    {
      // XXX crash here
      get_abstract().print();
    }

  private:
    struct abstract
    {
      virtual ~abstract(){}

      virtual void print() const = 0;
    };

    template<class T>
    struct concrete
    {
      concrete(const T& value) : value_(value) {}

      void print() const
      {
        std::cout << value_ << std::endl;
      }

      T value_;
    };

    abstract& get_abstract()
    {
      return *reinterpret_cast<abstract*>(&storage_);
    }

    const abstract& get_abstract() const
    {
      return *reinterpret_cast<const abstract*>(&storage_);
    }

    typename std::aligned_storage<4 * sizeof(void*)> storage_;
};

int main()
{
  small_object object(13);

  // XXX i expect this line to print '13' to the terminal but it crashes
  object.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Crashes at the lines indicated by `XXX`.

I believe the issue is that the virtual call to `.print()` is not being dynamically dispatched correctly, but I don't understand why.

Can anyone tell what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't derive `concrete<T>` from `abstract`, so no vtable is being created when you construct the object using placement `new`. Therefore, when you try to invoke the virtual function, it will fail; `concrete<T>` and `abstract` are actually completely unrelated types in this example.

I would recommend using the `override` keyword if you're using C++11 or newer to allow the compiler to generate an error in cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::aligned_storage<4 * sizeof(void*)> storage_;
```

This creates storage *of one byte*.

The template argument does not set the size of the declared object, but rather the size of an object that can be allocated in a suitably-sized array of this type. Hence, you need

```
std::aligned_storage<4 * sizeof(void*)> storage_[4 * sizeof(void*)];
```

GCC 6.2.0 warns you about this:

> warning: `placement new` constructing an object of type ‘`small_object::concrete<int>`’ and size ‘`16`’ in a region of type ‘`std::aligned_storage<32ul>`’ and size ‘`1`’ [-Wplacement-new=]

(You still need to derive `concrete` from `abstract`).